# Does $A_{17}$ have a subgroup of index $3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

I have an exercise which asks me whether the alternating group on $17$ letters $A_{17}$ has a subgroup of index 3.

I found the prime factorisation: $17!/2 = 3^{6}m$ for some integer $m$ coprime to $3$.

Now by Lagrange's Theorem I know that if there exists a subgroup of index $3$ it must have order $3^5m$, but I don't see how this is useful to prove that such a group exists or not.

And by the Sylow theorems I know that I can find a subgroup of order $3^6$. But I also don't know how this is applicable to my exercise.

If anybody could point me on the right path to go about this question, I would appreciate it. :)

Comment: Do you know that $A_n$ is simple for $n \geq 5$?

Comment: Yes, but the subgroup doesn't have to be normal, does it?
Because I can have that there exists some subgroup of index 3, but that the cosets of that subgroup do not themselves form a group, i.e. that the subgroup is not normal.

Comment: $S_n$ has no subgroup of index $m$ with $2<m<n$.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be normal. But every group acts on the cosets of each subgroup. So if $G$ has a subgroup of index $k$, then there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_k$.

Comment: @HongyiHuang I don't think your comment would be regarded as an acceptable solution to the exercise!

Comment: You might as well think about a more general problem (there's nothing special about $A_{17}$). No non-abelian simple group has a subgroup of index $3$. (Or $4$ for that matter, but try $3$ first.)

Comment: @the_fox that should be an answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do that :) Thank you

Comment: Okay, I think I have a solution.
I assume $\vert G \vert > 6$ (which is the case for $G = A_{17}$) . If $H \subseteq G$ such that $[G:H] = 3$.
Then since $G$ acts on $G/H$ there exists a non trivial group homomorphism, call it $f: G \to S_3$.
Now since $\vert S_3 \vert = 6$ and $\vert G \vert > 6$, we have that $ker(f) \neq \{id\}$. And since $f$ is non-trivial, we have $ker(f) \neq G$
But we also know that $ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. And so it follows that $G$ cannot be simple. In particular $G \neq A_{17}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Lemma:** If $H$ is a proper subgroup of $A_n$ with index $k$ and $n\geq 5$ then $k\geq n$.

**Proof:** We have a nontrivial homomorphism $\phi$ from $A_n$ to $S_k$  due to the action $A_n$ on the set of distinct left cosets of $H$. On the other hand, $\ker(\phi)$ is trivial, since $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$. Thus, $A_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_k$, which yields that $\dfrac{n!}{2}$ divides $k!$ by Lagrange theorem. Clearly, this is not possible when $k<n$ and $n\geq 5$. Thus, $k\geq n$ as desired.

Note that $A_{n-1}$ has index $n$ in $A_n$, and so this index smallest possible in $A_n$ by above lemma.

Answer (score 4):

The group $A_n$ for $n\ge 5$ has no subgroup $H$ of prime index $p\neq n$.

*Proof:* In fact, the homomorphism from $A_n$ to $S_p$ coming from $A_n$ acting on the cosets of $H$ is injective,  since it is not trivial and $A_n$ is simple for $n\ge 5$. Hence by Lagrange
$$
\frac{n!}{2} \mid p!
$$
However, this can only happen if $n = p$.

In particular, $A_n$ has no subgroup of index $3$ for all $n\ge 5$.